# user.isValidPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm new to node.js and mongodb, and I'm working on an authentication api using passport.js. I have a method in the user model named "isValidPassword", but i can't use it in the passport local strategy to sign in.

I always have "user.isValidPassword is not a function"

here's the user model

```
    const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'); 
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // Create Schema
    const  userSchema = new Schema({
        email: String,
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
        id_user: Number,
        username: String,
        nom: String,
        prenom: String,
        num_portable: Number,
        num_fix: Number,
        image: String
        }

    });

    // Hash password before saving the user
    userSchema.pre('save', async function (next){
        try {
            // Generate Salt for the password encryption
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(15);
            // Generate a hashed password using Salt
            const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
            // Re-assign the hashed password to the user's acuatl password
            this.password = passwordHash;
            next();
            console.log ('Salt: '+ salt);
            console.log ('Original password: ' + this.password);
            console.log ('Hashed Password: ' +passwordHash);
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    });
    // isValidPassword
    // Compare hashedpassword vs password stored in db
    userSchema.methods.isValidPassword  = async function(newPassword) {
        try {
            return await bcrypt.compare(newPassword, this.password);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error (error);
        }
    }
    // Create Module
    const User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
    // Export Module
    module.exports = User;
```

and here's when I used it in the passport local strategy

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async(email, password, done)=> {
    try {
        // Find user by the given email
        const user = User.findOne({email});
        // If the user doesn't existe, handle it
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        // else, check if the password is correct

        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        // if the password is wrong, handle it
        if(!isMatch){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
    }

}));
```

and when I tried to do "console.log(user)" I found that isValidPassword is among the methods !
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/guIdu.png]

I just need the that boolean from isValidPassword method

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: you have to create a separate function isValidPassword.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
but I already did, "userSchema.methods.isValidPassword  = async function(...){..}"
as far as i know, that's how you add a method to a mongodb schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it, it was a silly mistake..
The problem was here

```js
const user = User.findOne({email});
```

I forgot to put **await** before `User.findOne(...)` so basically it doesn't wait for a response from the database, and it returns an empty user object.