# "how can i solve this error in nodejs ? "

Tags: node.js

this is in Models I create method

```
// validate the password with passed-on user password
userSchema.methods.isValidatedPassword = async function (usersendPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(usersendPassword, this.password);
};
```

I am trying to use this

```
// trying to crypt password


const final user = User.isValidatedPassword(existing user)
```

```
TypeError: User.isValidatedPassword is not a function
at exports.login (E:\Important Data\working projects\Ecommerce Backend\controller\userController.js:70:26)
at the process.processTicksAndRejections (node: internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
POST /login 500 12 - 30.976 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You add your code **await** and then check

```
const final user = await User.isValidatedPassword(existing user)
```

More help please check it: [user.isValidPassword is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057704/user-isvalidpassword-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

`isValidatedPassword` is a method on a specific user object, not the `User` class. So you have to use one of the `User` class methods like `User.findOne({email});` to get a user instance that you can call `user.isValidatedPassword()` on.

You would do something like:

```
const user = await User.findOne({email});
const isValid = await user.isValidatedPassword(password);
```

Your `isValidatedPassword` function returns a boolean, so you should not be assigning it to the `user` variable.